# MEAN stack active:$uiRoute not working

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, mean.io

I've got the [MEAN stack](https://github.com/linnovate/mean) installed.

```
<!-- public/views/header.html -->
<li data-ng-repeat="item in menu" data-ng-show="global.user" ui-route="/{{item.link}}" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}">
```

Notice **ui-route="/{{item.link}}"** **ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}"**

When I do

```
/* public/css/common.css */

.active {
color: red !important;
}
```

When I'm on the active page, the link in the menu isn't highlighted. How do I highlight my current page?

Why would they put ui-route="/{{item.link}}" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}" in there if the highlighting doesn't work? Wishful thinking?

**Update**

The most current version of Mean.IO says this. It's also using the most current version of Angular UI-Router

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in menus.main" ui-route="/{{item.link}}" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}">
```

Comment: seems like some parts of it is missing it should be something like `{active: $uiRoute==item.link}`

Comment: Just tried it. No dice. Good suggestion! Keep the ideas coming :D

Answer (score 3):

What version of ui-router are you using??? The newest version is MUCH easier to get this sort of thing working. Download the new version and it's as simple as this:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in menu" data-ng-show="global.user" ui-sref="{{item.link}}" ui-sref-active="active">
```

Comment: Trying this with the latest angular ui-router (2.1 at the time of writing). Putting this code in, with or without data-ng-show="global.user" results in the links disappearing.

Comment: Thank you for making the effort to answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add **ui-sref-active="active"** to the a mean-token tag.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav nav">
  <li data-ng-repeat="item in menus.main" ui-route="/{{item.link}}" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}">

      <a mean-token="item.link" ui-sref='{{item.link}}' ui-sref-active="active">{{item.title}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Add .active class to common.css

```
.active {
color: red !important;
}
```